# Adding a separator (a <div> or a row separator) every 3 <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site that get a JSON data and populates the site, so I get an unknown numbers of items, this items are on columns of 3, I would like that after each row to have a a nice looking line.

When it was static content what I did was:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="separator"></div>
</ul>
```

but now that i get the dynamic content i dont know how to manage it.

Comment: That's not a valid HTML and the browser will not render it as such. You cannot have a `<div>` as a direct child of `<ul>`. Not possible. You may try using `<li class="separator"></li>` instead. Does it work?

Comment: ok but still i cant create a <li class="separator"></li> since its dynamic

Comment: Refresh my comment, I have added the alternative too.

Comment: I also did an edit why it doesnt work ( or at least i dont know how to make it work)

Comment: It's it's merely a formatting issue you can skip the class altogether and use CSS `:nth-of-type()` selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a valid HTML and the browser will not render it as such. You cannot have a `<div>` as a direct child of `<ul>`. **Not possible.** You may try using `<li class="separator"></li>` instead.

I would just use this small script to add a new `<li>` after every 3rd child:

```js
$(function () {
  $("li:nth-child(3n)").after("<li class='seperator' />");
});
```

```css
.seperator {
  background: #ccf;
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ... or just skip the `class` altogether and add the relevant formatting directly to `li:nth-of-type(3n)` in the CSS file.

Comment: @CD001 Yea, since you told that in the comment, I didn't add it. `:)`

Comment: @CD001 But sincerely I believe, he requires an element to be added and not CSS. `:)` Just my thought.

Comment: Fair enough,  you're probably right - good answer and gets a +1 from me ;)

Comment: makes sense ! thanks i'm trying it now.
i think i'm burnout for the day.. such a simple solution and i wouldn't think of it...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `:nth-child`-CSS-selector:

```css
li:nth-child(3n) {
  /* replace with whatever style you have for the seperators */
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I agree with this. But sincerely I believe, he requires an element to be added and not CSS. `:)` Just my thought.

Comment: Maybe you are right but I can't really imagine why one would need that. Even if OP wants content, there are still pseudo-elements. But in case he needs a special element, there is still your answer :)

Comment: Yep. Some crazy CMS's output... Ha ha... You might need to go beyond that mate. I have been in such crazy positions. `:(`